# Could Origen updater changes impact generated test flows or patterns?

Tags: origen-sdk

As I was going through and locking down specific tag versions in my app's Gemfile, I noticed the origen_updater gem had no version associated with it.

```
gem 'origen_updater'
```

Why is that?  I see that [it is version controlled](https://github.com/Origen-SDK/origen_updater/blob/master/config/version.rb).  Could changes to this gem impact modeling or generation?

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the only thing this gem does is copy its `fix_my_workspace` script to the application's bin directory.
See here for more background - http://origen-sdk.org/origen//guides/starting/workspace/?highlight=fix_my_workspace#Fix_My_Workspace

It is not versioned for the following reasons:

- The latest version of this script will always be the best, which by definition, will have the best chance of getting your workspace going again if it is in a broken state
- This script is intended to be called directly at times when either Origen or Bundler fail to launch. Finding out that you need a newer version of the script to fix your current problem is not very helpful if you are in a state where Bundler cannot be used to pull it in.

Therefore, the recommendation is not to lock this to a particular version and instead allow it to pull in the latest and greatest anytime you do a `bundle update`.